# PHP fopen does not work

Tags: php, fopen

I have a piece of code to count the hits of a webpage. I have a countlog.txt file which has only a number, say 1078, there. The code opens countlog.txt , reads the 1078 out, close the file. All these are fine.

After operation on the 1078, the codes opens countlog.txt agian, trying to write back, and could not open it!

It should not be the permission or path problem, because the first time it works. It should not be the first fclose problem since there is an "or die" there.

This is the code:

```
/* counter */

//opens countlog.txt to read the number of hits

$dateo = fopen("/htdocs/www/mypath/countlog.txt","r") ;
$count = fgets($dateo, 1000);
echo $count."<br>";
fclose($dateo) or die("apple");
$count=$count + 1 ;
echo "$count" ;
echo " hits" ;
echo "\n" ;

// opens countlog.txt to change new hit number
$dateo = fopen("/htdocs/www/mypath/countlog.txt","w") or die("grape");
fwrite($dateo, $count);
fclose($dateo);
```

This is the output:

```
1078
1079 hits grape
```

The grape shows!

Please help!

Comment: This is a really bad way to try to manage data. You are most likely experiencing a permissions issue, but it will also fail due to contention and running the script in a chroot environment. I would **strongly** recommend you use a proper DBMS for this (although its *possible* to do with files, it requires a level of sophistication several orders of magnitude greater than what you've shown here).

Comment: Thank you! Yes you are right. I am thinking it is not a good and save way. My current project is to set an online survey, and I want to get a unique id as the survey id. I though the hit count maybe useful. But it is not a good idea... Do you have any suggestion on retrieve a unique ID from webpage? Thank you!!

Comment: uniqid() seems the obvious candidate

Comment: Thank you! It does not work. Alway shows 55. I used time(). :-(

Answer (score 0):

Why do you assume it's not a permissions problem?  It sounds like your web server has read permissions, but does not have write permissions.